# phonegap webos 3.0+

Tags: node.js, cordova, webos

I have a phonegap iOS app that i ported to webos on the touchpad the app works great except for the one iOS plugin that i used.  it basically saved the canvas data to the photo roll.  From my understanding of webos i will need to create a node.js service and write the data to a buffer and finally to the file system, there is an example for that in the forums.  however what i can not figure out is how to call all of this from my phonegap app.  I believe i will need to have the following in my index.html file.

```
    <script src="/opt/PalmSDK/Current/share/framework/enyo/1.0/framework/enyo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

and something like
    enyo.create({kind: "Main"}).renderInto(document.body);
```

my guess i will also have to have all of the "kind" data in a js file.  but how do i do the little step from my app's js file to communicate with the service that is created.  I looked in the phonegap 1.0.js file and see that they are calling services this way.

```
            this.service = navigator.service.Request('palm://com.palm.applicationManager', {
    method: 'launch',
    parameters: {
    id: 'com.palm.app.camera',
    params: {
            appId: 'com.palm.app.camera',
            name: 'capture',
            sublaunch: true,
            filename: filename
        }
    },
    onSuccess: successCallback,
    onFailure: errorCallback
});
```

but i also noticed it appears that it is all mojo and what i am doing is enyo, so yes i am pretty confused the moment...

seems it should be easy to call a service in webos, say here is a string of image data and write it to the file system from my existing phonegap app.  and not have to do everything in enyo.  anyone have a sample of a webos plugin like this or know where to point me?

thanks tim

****Update

I have created a node service now as defined below, i think that works and i am trying to make the call to the service, but it does not get to it. the test app runs on my touchpad, but when i push the button to save the image i do not get into the service.  I tried to follow what was done for the camera in the phonegap0.0.1.js file  this is a copy of my service, how i defined it and how i am calling it.  any ideas what i am doing wrong.

services.json =

```
"id": "com.tim.pgmojo1.service",
"description": "FileIO Service",
"services": [
  {
"name": "com.tim.pgmojo1.service",
"description": "FileIO Service",
"commands": [
    {
      "name": "writefile",
      "assistant": "WriteFileAssistant",
      "public": true
    }]
  }]
}
```

****   service code
    var libraries = MojoLoader.require({ name: "foundations", version: "1.0" });
    var fs = IMPORTS.require("fs");
    var sys = require('sys');

```
var WriteFileAssistant = function() {}

WriteFileAssistant.prototype.run = function(future) {
 var mypath = this.controller.args.thepath;
 var mydata = this.controller.args.thedata;
 console.log("in write file");
 console.log("path=" + thepath);
 console.log("image data=" + thedata);

 var data = content.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
 var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
 fs.writeFile('/media/internal/downloads/timimage.png', buf);
}
```

my call to the service******

this.service = navigator.service.Request('palm://com.tim.pgmojo.service', {
        method: 'writefile',
        parameters: {

```
            thepath: '/media/internal/downloads/timimage.png',
            thedata: canvasData
    },
    onSuccess: mySuccess,
    onFailure: myFailure
});
```

currently i have this in my index.html file since it is only for testing..

Answer (score 0):

Mojo is still included on the TouchPad.  You can use the same service-calling functions as PhoneGap is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In Enyo, access to on-device services is handled by the enyo.PalmService kind.  You can see an example of an app that has a node.js service included and how calls are made to this service at https://github.com/palm/txjs-fortunecookie